# Перевод предупреждения о запрете использовать метку untagged

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

При попытке задать вопрос с меткой [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) показывается непереведённое предупреждение о запрете использовать эту метку:

> This tag is for use by the system for questions that have had all other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead.

> [image: предупреждение о запрете использовать метку untagged]

Это предупреждение можно перевести так:

> Эта метка используется системой для вопросов, у которых все остальные метки удалены. Пожалуйста, используйте [настоящие метки](link_to_tags).

Comment: Текста нет в Transifex. На MSE заведёте баг?

Comment: Да, [завёл](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304086/359876)

Comment: @älёxölüt а воз и ныне там.

Comment: @Suvitruf слишком много всего **на возе** :)

Comment: @älёxölüt слишком много зайцев.

Answer (score 1):

Перевод добавлен при содействии [SpencerG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/457649/spencerg):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на мете этого нет. Хотя должно быть.

Comment: @Зонтик если ты про MSE, то там сказано, что решения должны быть на локальных метах. Что, собственно, и имеем.

Comment: На мете нет - то есть на нашей мете нет этого описания при попытке прикрепить метку [meta-tag:untagged] к вопросу. Вернее, оно есть, но на английском.

Comment: @Зонтик м-да, интересно, но объяснимо. Всё же метки на основном и мета сайтах разные. Но вот эта специальная, конечно, могла бы шариться на оба.

Comment: @Зонтик для меты тоже теперь есть.

Comment: Спасибо вам за это!